# Hosting WCF Service on IIS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf, iis

I am new to WCF and windows mobile development. I am trying to create an occasionally connected application that utilizes the MSFT sync framework and this requires the use of a WCF service.

I have a visual studio project containing my smart device project, a WCF Service Library project, and a WCF Service website project.

The service is hosted fine on my local machine not using IIS and I can access it at `http://localhost:55149/ElectricReadingServiceSite/ElectricReading.svc`

However when I add it to IIS it gives me an http 404 resource cannot be found error. I cannot figure out why it thinks the resource is not there.

Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncService" 
               behaviorConfiguration="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint 
            address=""  
            binding="basicHttpBinding"  
            contract="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.IElectricReadingCacheSyncContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="10.104.238.123"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My `ElectricReading.svc` looks like this:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
        Service="MiddleTierServiceLibrary.ElectricReadingCacheSyncService" %>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Are there any tools or steps I can take to get a better idea of what is going wrong? The 404 error does very little to help me.

Comment: Have you checked iis configuration? Sometime WCF is not default installed with IIS and you should do this manually.

Comment: Are you accessing the URL the ServiceHost port # (55149), or by the default port 80 (ie, plain URL)?

Comment: What URL are you using to access the WCF service that's hosted on IIS?

Comment: @BojanSkrchevski I am using "http://localhost/WCFTest/ElectricReading.svc" to access it through IIS. (added application with alias WCFTest and pointed to WCF Service Web Site on local machine) - If I look at content view I can see everything is there (web.config and the .svc)

Comment: @RoBYCoNTe how do you make sure it is configured correctly? The .svc is in the Handler Mappings, is that all I need?

Comment: Which version of IIS are you using? I had the same problem with IIS6, the problem was that in web server extensions section, "ASP.NET V..." state was prohibited and I changed it to Allowed, and the problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a number of reasons to why this could be happening.

Some of them might include:

- Make sure you uploaded the assembly in the Bin folder
- You have set up a website on IIS, but you are not accessing it with
  the correct address(make sure the port is correct)
- Your application pool is not set up for the website(if you are using
  .NET 4.0 you need to set the applictation pool to version 4.0) In IIS manager go to ApplicationPools and set the pool to the version of .NET that you are using

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It should log the calls it makes and thus give you a little more detail on what it is not finding.